# Create binary tensor, given a 2d tensor with indices in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I need a tensor that is somewhat similar to what `tf.one_hot` gives me, but I (sometimes) need more then one `1` in every row.

To be more specific, given a 2d tensor A I need a 2d tensor that has a `1` at a certain position, if and only if A contains the column index as a value in the same row.

To make matters worse, my given tensor A is of dynamic size and padded, but an additional 1d tensor provides me with the actual lengths.

What is an efficient (memory and time) way to do this?

Some context for the question:
I am doing a multi class classification with a variable subset of labels for each example.
Thus I calculate the exponential for the softmax and want to subtract a big number from the non relevant class labels.

As an example, given input:

```
indices = [[1, 4, 2, 5], [0, 4, 2, 0], [2, 4, 0, 0]]
real_length = [4, 3, 2]
shape = [3, 5]
```

where `indices` is my padded 2d tensor (0 paddings at the end) where each value indicates which value should be set to `1` in the output tensor.
`real_length` indicates how many values (from left) in each row of `indices` are non-padding values.
`shape` is the shape of the output tensor I need, where the first dimension is the same as `indices` and the second dimension is the maximum value any value in `indices` may take, but not necessarily the maximum over `indices`.

I need:

```
[[0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1], [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0]]
```

Comment: Could you please provide a reason for the down vote?

Answer (score 0):

For multiple hot encoding :

**Method 1**

You could do this using tf.nn.embeddings_lookup as shown here:

```
embeddings = tf.constant([[0,0,0], [0,0,1], [0,1,1], [1,1,1]])
labels = np.array([0,3,1,2,0])
encode_tensors = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(embeddings,labels)
sess.run(encode_tensors)
```

Output :

```
array([[0, 0, 0],
      [1, 1, 1],
      [0, 0, 1],
      [0, 1, 1],
      [0, 0, 0]], dtype=int32)
```

**Method 2**

```
labels = np.array([1, 2, 0, 3, 0])
sess.run(tf.sequence_mask(labels, 3, dtype=tf.int8))
```

Output :

```
array([[1, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 0]], dtype=int8)
```

Hope this helps !

Comment: The first method is pretty inefficient for already moderate sizes embedding lengths. And unfortunately the 2nd method doesn't help me, as I need interspersed 0 and 1s, I'll try and clarify the question somewhat.

Comment: could you give an example of what you need specifically ?

Comment: Isn't it first one supposed to be [0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1] ??

Comment: Sorry, your example is difficult to understand. (my bad) Could you explain why real_length and shape are useful ?

Comment: Edited the question. I'm pretty tired and am having a hard time expressing myself. Thank your for bearing with me though!

Comment: in that case, why there are only 3 ones in first tensor ? there should be 4 right ??

Comment: My bad, fixed it.

Comment: thanks for updating it. People get confused with that.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I completely understood all details of your question, a good starting point (that will produce your desired output from the indices) would be:

```
indices = [[1, 4, 2, 5], [0, 4, 2, 0], [2, 4, 0, 0]]
one_hots = tf.one_hot(indices, 6)
tf.reduce_max(one_hots, axis=1)
```

(where 6 is the second dimension of your desired output)
which produces:

```
[[0., 1., 1., 0., 1., 1.],
 [1., 0., 1., 0., 1., 0.],
 [1., 0., 1., 0., 1., 0.]]
```

So, with `one_hot` you basically create a tensor of shape (3, 4, 6) containing all the single one_hot encodings for every element in index.
Then, you collapse them all into a single "multi-hot" representation getting rid of the second dimension of your indices.

Since it doesn't perform any lookup, but it's just a simple one_hot encoding + a max operation, I think it would be efficient enough.

Hope It helped :)